# Wieso spricht man die Namen der Buchstaben H und K mit einem A-Laut am Ende aus?

Tags: pronunciation

Wieso spricht man die Namen der Buchstaben H und K mit einem A-Laut am Ende aus, anstelle eines E-Lautes, wie etwa beim G?
(G deshalb, weil es ja eigentlich nur ein stimmhaftes K ist.)

Mir ist bewusst, dass nicht alle anderen Buchstaben mit einer Kombination mit E ["benannt"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsches_Alphabet#Benennung_der_Buchstaben) werden, aber aus welchem Grund tanzen auch diese zwei aus der Reihe?

Comment: Wäre es hilfreich, zumindest in Gruppen die 26 "Norm-"Buchstaben bzw. nur die Konsonanten des dt. Alphabets mit ihrer Aussprache in die Frage aufzunehmen? Dass erkenntlich wird, wer wie aus der Reihe tanzt? Das würde ich für die gewünschte Integration von verlinkten Seiten halten.

Comment: Bitte beachte, dass im Deutschen alle Substantive großgeschrieben werden. Dazu gehören auch alle Namen, und unter anderem auch die Namen von Buchstaben. Wenn du also z.B. etwas über den Buchstaben H schreibst, ist dieses H ein Substantiv das großgeschrieben werden muss. Das gilt auch für Zusammensetzungen wie z.B. *A-Laut.* Ich habe das in deiner Frage korrigiert, und habe auch klargemacht, dass es in deiner Frage nicht (wie ursprünglich formuliert) um die Aussprache der Buchstaben geht, sondern um die Aussprache der Namen der Buchstaben. Das sind zwei völlig verschiedenen Dinge.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Wieso hast du das "a" in "a-Laut" im Titel klein gelassen?

Comment: @355durch113: Weil ich es da übersehen hatte.

Comment: See also https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/732/what-are-the-classical-names-of-the-letters-of-the-latin-alphabet/733#733

Answer (score 5):

Dies dürfte letztlich von etruskischen Buchstabennamen herrühren, die in lateinischer Adaptation ins Deutsche übernommen wurden. Anders als im griechischen Alphabet gehen sie nicht auf die ursprünglichen semitischen Namen zurück. Stattdessen richten sie sich nach der Aussprache. Dabei gibt es drei Arten von regulären Bezeichnungen:

1. Vokale können alleine gesprochen werden. Also bezeichnen sie sich selber: A, E, I, O, V
2. Kontinuanten können ebenfalls alleine gesprochen werden: F, L, M, N, R, S. Im Etruskischen sind silbische Kontinuanten offenbar nicht unüblich gewesen.
3. Verschlusslaute können nur schlecht alleine gesprochen werden – nach der Plosion ergibt sich fast unweigerlich ein Schwa: Cə, Də, Gə, Pə, Tə

Als die Römer mit ihrer vokalreichen Sprache ohne silbische Konsonanten oder Schwa das Alphabet von den Etruskern übernahmen, hätten sie vor den silbischen Kontinuanten ein E eingefügt und ebenfalls nach den Verschlusslauten anstelle des Schwas.

Neben den regulären gibt es verschiedene irreguläre Buchstabennamen:

- Für den Laut /k/ gab es drei verschiedene Zeichen. Die ursprüngliche Verteilung richtete sich im Etruskischen und im archaischen Latein nach dem folgenden Laut: C vor E und I, K vor A und Q vor O und V. Daher kämen die Namen, damit man die drei /k/ unterscheiden kann. Die Römer jedenfalls verwendeten die drei Namen (regulär: CE, irregulär: KA und QV) nach etruskischer Buchstabenverteilung, auch als sie später ausser in QV fast nur noch C verwendeten.
- H hat alleine gesprochen keinen wirklichen Klang. Das Namenschema der Kontinuanten bietet sich nicht an, denn *EH wäre leicht mit E zu verwechseln, und ausserdem gibt es im Latein das H nur vor Vokalen. Das Namenschema der Verschlusslaute bietet sich ebenfalls nicht an, denn H ist kein Verschlusslaut. Vielleicht wurde deshalb der Name HA verwendet, mit dem klangreichsten Vokal A? Noch in der Antike wurde das H im Lateinischen stumm, so dass der Name gleich lautete wie A. Also wurde ACCA als neuer Name verwendet.

Comment: Wie ist das mit den "Kontinuanten" gemeint? Man sagt doch Ef, Em, En etc.

Comment: Interessante Theorie. Das Wissen zur **Aussprache** des Etruskischen dürfte eher gering sein, und warum die vermeintliche etruskische Aussprache sich nur ins Deutsche und nicht z.B. ins Englische übetrragen hat, erschließt sich mir nicht.

Comment: @PaulFrost Stichwort [Great Vowel Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift)

Comment: @idmean: Du kannst MMMMMM, LLLLLLL, FFFFFFF usw. beliebig lange für sich alleine aussprechen (genau darum heissen die Laute auch Kontinuanten oder Dauerlaute). Bei B, D, K usw. verhält es sich nicht so.

Comment: @PaulFrost: Zum Etruskischen und seiner Aussprache ist eben doch erstaunlich viel bekannt, vgl. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etruscan_language und die weiterführende Literatur dort. Der englische Name _aitch_ geht nicht auf HA zurück, sondern auf den alternativen Namen ACCA, der auch im Italienischen usw. gebraucht wird und der wohl entstanden ist, nachdem das H im Lateinischen stumm geworden war.

Comment: @mach Ich schreibe hier nur als Laie. Es ist mir bekannt, dass zahlreiche etruskische Inschriften erhalten sind, allerdings ist laut https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etruskische_Sprache wenig über die Wortbedeutung bekannt. "Etwa 200 etruskische Wörter sind mehr oder weniger gedeutet, die Bedeutung der restlichen etwa 300–400 Wörter ist noch unklar. Die Deutungen der einzelnen Forscher gehen z. T. immer noch weit auseinander und sollten kritisch betrachtet werden." Ich behaupte (ohne Beweis), dass zur Aussprache allenfalls spekuliert werden kann. Vielleicht gibt es über römische Zeugisse

Comment: Rückschlussmöglichkeiten in dieser Hinsicht. Ich bezweifle aber, dass die Aussprache einzelner Konsonanten ("ha", "ka", "em") - falls Buchstabieren im Etruskischen überhaupt üblich war - erhalten blieb. Dass das Lateinische eine mögliche Aussprache aus dem Etruskischen übernommen hat, ist denkbar, aber ohne Beleg. Die Sprachen sind jedenfalls nicht wirklich verwandt. Dass in den romanischen Sprachen die lateinische Art des Buchstabierens gepflegt wird, ist nicht überraschend. Auch in anderen europäischen Sprachen wurde durch die Missiontätigkeit der katholischen Kirche ab dem frühen

Comment: Mittelalter ("Klosterschulen") mit Sicherkeit das lateinische Buchstabieren eingeübt, zumal lange überhaupt nur lateinisch geschrieben wurde. Interessant ist m.E., dass im Griechischen die Buchstaben meist völlig anders ausgesprochen werden ("kappa" - "ka", aber "lamdba" - "el", "gamma"- "ge"). Im Russischen, dessen Alphabet sich aus dem Griechischen ableitet, werden übrigens die Konsonanten wie im Lateinischen ausgesprochen. Vgl. https://www.russlandjournal.de/russisch-lernen/russisches-alphabet/. Mein Fazit (vielleicht Unsinn?): Die Herkunft aus dem Etruskischen ist rein spekulativ.

Comment: @PaulFrost: Selbstverständlich ist die Antwort spekulativ. Es ist aber eine fundierte Spekulation, und nicht einfach aus der Luft gegriffen – ähnlich wie letztlich auch (aber viel laienhafter als) die Literatur, auf die ich verwiesen habe. Ich meine, man könnte ja auch einfach sagen, es ist so, weil es im Latein so war. Das ist aber eine unfertige Erklärung, denn es zwingt sich die Folgefrage auf, warum war es denn im Latein so? Jedenfalls habe ich nun verstärkt die grammatischen Mittel des Deutschen eingesetzt, um Spekulativität zu signalisieren.

Answer (score 4):

Das deutsche Alphabet und seine Aussprache basiert zu großen Teilen auf dem lateinischen Alphabet. Dieses basiert seinerseits auf dem griechischen, übernimmt allerdings nicht dessen Aussprache für die einzelnen Buchstaben.

[Stattdessen werden diese wie folgt ausgesprochen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateinisches_Alphabet#Namen_der_Buchstaben):

- Vokale bezeichnen sich selber (a, e, i, o, u)
- Plosive fügen ein e an (be, ce, de usw.)
- Dauerlaute – Frikative und Sonorante – bekommen ein e vorangestellt (ef, el, em usw.)

Buchstaben wie K und Q bilden allerdings eine Ausnahme. Diese werden mit denen für sie normalerweise verbundenen Vokalen ausgesprochen.

- k -> ka (IPA dt:  [kaː])
- q -> qu (IPA dt: [kuː], österr. [kveː])

Der [Ursprung für die Aussprache des K + Q](https://www.weikopf.de/lateinisches-alphabet.html) liegen (wahrscheinlich) in der Art, wie das griechische Alphabet zu den Römern kam. Diese übernahmen (wahrscheinlich) das Alphabet von den Etruskern, die es selbst von griechischen Siedlern übernommen hatten.

Die etruskische Sprache beinhaltete drei k-Laute, für die Buchstaben gebraucht wurden. Diese wurden

> - Der griechische Buchstabe Γ (für [g]) zur Darstellung des stimmlosen Verschlusses [k] vor den Vokalen e und i
> - Das griechische Κ, um [k] vor a wiederzugeben
> - Das archaisch-griechische Symbol Ϙ für [k] vor u

Was von den Römern übernommen und mit der Zeit verfeinert wurde (unter anderem entstand so aus einer Abwandlung des C unser G).

([Quelle](https://www.weikopf.de/lateinisches-alphabet.html))

---

Und das H ([haː])?

Vermutung ohne eine Quelle gefunden zu haben:  Weil es griechisch schon Eta hieß ^^ .

Allerdings übernahmen die Römer den Buchstaben und seine Aussprache ebenfalls von den Etruskern. Die Schreibweise allerdings vom Griechischen.

([Quelle](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/H#Herkunft))